# We are trying to paint n chairs with the colors R,G,B. In how many ways can this be done given that both the number of R&B chairs must be odd.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

so I am trying to attack the above question but I am kind of stuck. I have figured out the following:

1. The number of ways to paint the n chairs = $ 3^n$
2. The number of ways to to paint red and blue such that they are odd = number of ways to paint red such that they are odd $ \times $ number of ways to paint blue such that they are odd
3. The result is 1 - 2

I am stuck on number 2, how would I go about thinking about how many ways can I arrange n chairs so that they are odd?

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: The question is not very clear. I'm not sure what it means for "chairs to be odd". Can you give the exact text of the problem, word-for-word?

Comment: I apologize for that. 

We are trying to paint n chairs with the colors red, green and blue. In how many ways can this be done given that both the number of red and blue chairs must be odd.

Comment: You are assuming the chairs are distinct before they are painted based on your $3^n$.  Is that correct?  You can't just multiply the ways to paint an odd number red by the ways to paint an odd number blue because they are interdependent.  If $n$ is odd, you could paint $n-2$ chairs red, but then you must paint $1$ chair blue.

Answer (score 3):

Let $a_n$ be the number of ways to paint $n$ indistinguishable chairs with both red and blue odd.  Equivalently, $a_n$ is the number of nonnegative integer solutions to $x_1+x_2+x_3=n$ with both $x_1$ and $x_2$ odd. Let $A(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$ be the ordinary generating function (OGF) for $a_n$.  Now the OGF for the positive odd integers is $z^1+z^3+z^5+\dots=z/(1-z^2)$, and the OGF for the nonnegative integers is $z^0+z^1+z^2+\dots=1/(1-z)$.  Because $a_n$ counts the combinations of the form (odd, odd, nonnegative), we have
\begin{align}
A(z)&=(z^1+z^3+z^5+\dots)^2(z^0+z^1+z^2+\dots)\\
&=\left(\frac{z}{1-z^2}\right)^2\frac{1}{1-z}\\
&=\frac{z^2}{(1+z)^2(1-z)^3}.
\end{align}
Partial fraction decomposition then yields
$$A(z)= \frac{-1/16}{1+z} + \frac{1/8}{(1+z)^2} - \frac{1/16}{1-z} - \frac{1/4}{(1-z)^2} + \frac{1/4}{(1-z)^3},$$
from which we immediately obtain the explicit formula
$$a_n=\frac{-1}{16}(-1)^n + \frac{1}{8}(-1)^n(n+1) - \frac{1}{16} - \frac{1}{4}(n+1) + \frac{1}{4}\binom{n+2}{2},$$
which simplifies to
$$a_n = \frac{2 n^2 + 2 ((-1)^n + 1) n + (-1)^n - 1}{16}.$$

Comment: Is there any chance you can expand a little on the logic of the generating function, and how it contributes on a low level to count the ways?

Answer (score 0):

Let the total number of red and blue chairs be $k$, which must be even and at least $2$.  There are $n \choose k$ ways to choose the chairs to paint red and blue.  Half of the $2^k$ subsets of the red/blue chairs have an odd number of members.  Let the subset be the ones painted red.  The total number of ways is then
$$\sum_{\stackrel{k=2}{k \text{ even}}}^{2\lfloor \frac n2 \rfloor}{n \choose k}2^{k-1}$$

Comment: This formula cannot be correct.  It yields 2 when $n=2$, but the correct count is 1 from (1R, 1B, 0G).

Comment: It all depends on whether the question views the chairs as distinct (see Ross's comment on the original question).  Ross and I answered the question where they are distinct (say numbered 1 to n).  You (Rob) answered the question where they are not distinct (so you only care about how many chairs are painted each colour).  So what you regard as one solution (1R, 1B,0G) is indeed two solutions from mine and Ross's point of view (RB and BR).  Only skidjoe can tell us which question he asked, though all 3 solutions are nice approaches regardless.

Comment: I see.  This sum reduces to $(3^n-2+(-1)^n)/4$, which is a much simpler formula than for the indistinguishable case, so I suspect that @skidjoe meant for the chairs to be distinguishable..

Comment: @RobPratt Yes that is the "nice simple formula" I was referring to in my answer.

Comment: I appreciate the effort guys! Unfortunately the question does not state whether they are distinguishable, however, if I had to guess, I would say that they are indistinguishable.

Comment: @skidjoe:  if you think they are indistinguishable, your $3^n$ is badly off.  That counts on each chair being able to be painted one of three colors.  If they are indistinguishable, all you care about is how many are painted each color.

Answer (score 0):

Given n chairs, let ${\bf v}_n$ be the column vector whose four entries are:

1) The number of ways that both the number of red chairs and number of blue chairs are even,

2) The number of ways that the number of red chairs is odd and the number blue chairs is even,

3) The number of ways that the number of red chairs is even but the number of blue chairs is odd,

4) The number of ways that both the number of red chairs and number of blue chairs is odd.

Write down a matrix $M$ such that $M{\bf v}_n={\bf v}_{n+1}$ (just think about what happens if you add a chair of each colour to an existing sequence of coloured chairs).  Clearly ${\bf v}_0=(1 0 0 0)^T$, as with $0$ chairs, both the number of red chairs and number of blue chairs must be even.  Thus you just want the 4th entry of $M^n(1 0 0 0)^T$.

Now you just need to write $(1 0 0 0)^T$ as a linear combination of eigenvectors of $M$, so you can multiply through by $M^n$ and read off the bottom row to get a nice simple formula for your answer (that will not involve any sums or factorials for that matter).

Finding the eigenvectors is much easier than you might expect.  Looking at the matrix it is clear that 1 is an eigenvalue and it gives you two eigenvectors.  The sum of each row of the matrix is the same, so (1111)^T is an eigenvector.  Finally the matrix is symmetric, so eignenspaces are orthogonal, and you just need to take a vector orthogonal to your first 3 eigenvectors, to get the 4th.